Airquality data with multiple variables: a request please
Apologies if my question is not appropriate to this site. I am working on a project that requires multivariate air quality data with a specific structure. I have searched for about two weeks but have only found data from the scopula package, specifically the 'EU_RB' for air quality. However, this data only contains one variable, which is unsuitable for my project. The structure of the data is as follows:
I need data with a similar structure but more than one variable. The shown data has only PM10 as a variable
 > str(EU_RB)
Formal class 'STFDF' [package "spacetime"] with 4 slots
  ..@ data   :'data.frame': 11834 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ PM10: num [1:11834] 14 9.7 7.8 21.9 11.2 9 11 6.1 7.4 7.4 ...
  .. ..$ EMEP: num [1:11834] 11.62 5.02 3.94 3.82 7.01 ...
  ..@ sp     :Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ data       :'data.frame':   194 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. .. ..$ station_altitude: int [1:194] 525 581 918 560 172 117 665 1137 330 330 ...
  .. .. ..@ coords.nrs : num(0) 
  .. .. ..@ coords     : num [1:194, 1:2] 4592866 4761515 4658756 4690954 4799839 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "coords.x1" "coords.x2"
  .. .. ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 2749697 1647732 6412269 4604814
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "coords.x1" "coords.x2"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  .. .. ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. ..@ projargs: chr " +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
  ..@ time   :An xts object on 2005-06-01 / 2005-07-31 containing: 
  Data:    integer [61, 1]
  Columns: ..1
  Index:   POSIXct,POSIXt [61] (TZ: "GMT")
  ..@ endTime: POSIXct[1:61], format: "2005-06-02 03:00:00" "2005-06-03 03:00:00" "2005-06-04 03:00:00" ...

